# Image and kernel of transposed maps

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

> Let $U,V,W$ be vector spaces over a field $K$ and $\varphi: U\to V,$  $\psi: V\to W$ linear maps. Given that
> $\text{ker}(\psi)=\text{im}(\varphi)$ show that $\ker(\varphi^{tr})=\operatorname{im}(\psi^{tr})$

I tried proving this by double inclusion.
So far I have:

$"\subseteq"$

Let $x \in \text{im}(\psi^{tr}),$ then I know there exists $\alpha \in W^*$ such that $\alpha \circ \psi=x$ and $\varphi^{tr}(\alpha \circ \psi)=\alpha \circ \psi \circ \varphi$ is the zero mapping as $\ker(\psi)=\operatorname{im}(\varphi)$.

Can someone help me with the other inclusion?

Comment: Are you familiar with the relationships between kernels and images of a linear map and its dual / transpose?

Comment: $\ker(\varphi^{tr})=\{f\in V^*\mid f(\operatorname{im}\varphi)=0\},$ and $\operatorname{im}(\psi^{tr})=\{f\in V^*\mid f(\ker\psi)=0\}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\alpha \in \ker(\varphi^{tr})$, then $\alpha\circ\varphi$ is the zero map. By $\ker(\psi)=Im(\varphi)$, it follows that $\alpha|_{\ker(\psi)}=0$, it means that $\alpha \in (\ker \psi)^0$ (the annihilator of $\psi$) from [This Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537884/image-of-dual-map-is-annihilator-of-kernel) it follows that $\alpha \in Im(\psi^{tr})$.